# How to filter from RDD in Pypsark

Tags: filter, pyspark, rdd

I would like to filter data from from RDD below.

```
  [Row(item_id='2388457', amount='900', city='Cincinnati'),
   Row(item_id='2455019', amount='3500',city='Cleveland'),
   Row(item_id='2455123', amount='1500',city='Cleveland')]
```

I need filtering of (city='Cleveland and amount>1000) how can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Have you tried the `filter` function? Is your code producing the wrong output? An error message?

Comment: rdd.filter(city='Cleveland').take(5) not working

Comment: you have to pass a function into `filter` - `rdd.filter(lambda x: x['city'] == 'Kayseri')`

Comment: thanks man but I got error SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment

Comment: double equals for equality check.

Comment: `rdd.filter( lambda x : (x['city'] == 'Cleveland') & (x['amount'] > 1000)).take(5)` gives 
`[Row(item_id=2455019, amount=3500, city=u'Cleveland'), Row(item_id=2455123, amount=1500, city=u'Cleveland')]`

Comment: thanks you very much

Comment: Actually it works with x['amount'] > '1000'

Answer (score 2):

You can [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.filter) the RDD using a lambda expression:

```
filtered_rdd = my_rdd.filter(lambda x: x['city'] == 'Cleveland' and x['amount'] > 1000)
```

You also might want to consider converting the numbers in your RDD into `float`/`int` values.